# reading C array in python

Tags: python, c, arrays, binary

Can python take in a C array (from a file) and does some processing on it? For example, say I have a C header containing:

```
static char bin[] = {...}; // whole bunch of hex values
```

Can I write a python script to count how many bytes are there in the array? The reason I want to do this is I have about ~100 of these headers and some of them have the same array names, so I can't include all of these and sizeof each one. 
Any suggestion on what should I look into? Doesn't have to be python but I feel like this is the right tool.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This Perl one-liner may help, if array initializers do not span multi-lines:

```
perl -lne '($p)=($_=~/static char bin\[\] = \{([^}]*)\}/) and
      $p=~s/[^,]*//g; print length($p)' input.h
```

Comment: unfortunately they do.. they're about several hundreds lines each, but thanks anyways I could try to tweak this a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt at a python version:

If the values in each array are comma separated, you could try the following:

```
import glob

#get all the headers in the current directory
headers = glob.glob("*.h")

for header in headers:
    fp = open(header, "r")
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line.startswith("static char"):
            bits = line.split(",")
            count = len(bits)-1
            print "Found array starting %s"%bits[0]
            print "containing %d bytes"%count
            print "in file %s"%header
```

This makes a few assumptions like the comma separation, and just prints out what it finds - what you do with the information is up to you - this wasn't clear in the question

Comment: I guess, regular expression will be better here. Your solution will fail for `static char function()`, `static char b[] = {1, 2, 3} /* , , */` and multiline definitions. Also your solution gives incorrect output for `static char b[] = {1, 2, 3};` - `containing 2 bytes`.